# How to crop image not based on screen size?

Tags: android, size, wallpaper

I recently asked a question and I think, I understood my problem([Why I get defected image from ImageCropper( android wallpaper app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027649/why-i-get-defected-image-from-imagecropper-android-wallpaper-app)). When I crop the area, it takes sizes of that area(small enough) and when i set it like a wallpaper it increases size and i loose quality. So, I am exactly sure that I must change something here:

```
public void performCrop(Uri picUri, int width, int height){
    try {
        utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext());
        int height1, width1;
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        height1 = size.y;
        width1 = size.x;


        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", width1*5);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", height1*5);
        //indicate  X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", width);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", height);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult

        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 1);

    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me? Please, if possible, show code.

Comment: So, I'm an IOS developer, but I may have some sort of an answer for you, you need to think about what you are doing when you allow the user or yourself to crop the image, you should restrict cropping the image to the MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) of the user's device so that it always appears BEAUTIFUL. This means that the image can only be cropped so much. There's no single efficient Algorithm that can upscale cropped images to "look good" in either CLang or Java. Despite what others may say, "up scaling" an image always makes the image look like sh%t.

Comment: furthermore, why don't you have a look at this: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Comment: Yeah, but android system cropper apps, doesn't allow me to scale pictures and so one. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Yep, you don't have to scale the image, I assume that you could create a camera "overly" or a message where you restrict the cropping to a certain dimension. In IOS for example, I can GET the value of the User's Iphone height and width and then determine what the cropping area should be restricted to for this particular user give the iphone dimensions. That's what I'm saying, you don't need to scale the images, don't UP scale anything, just only allow cropping within a certain height/width criteria

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is that you should allow cropping to the LARGEST screen size of an android phone. This means that ALL devices that use this image will downsize this image to fit as a wallpaper and always look good, but if you crop an image from a small scree size phone, then these images won't look good on larger Android devices

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) -- please use one.